# "Select all" option for FilePicker

Tags: c#, uwp, filepicker

Is there a possibility to add a "Select all" option if I call the `PickMultipleFilesAsync` method of a `FilePicker` object.

```
// Create the songs picker
var songsPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
songsPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
songsPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
songsPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
songsPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
songsPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");

var inputFiles = await songsPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync(); // Let the user pick the songs
```

If the user wants to pick more than one song he has to pick them one at the time. And picking 437 Songs one after another isn't a very good user experience.

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you cannot modify at this level the `FileOpenPicker`'s UI.

Alternative way you can pick a whole folder with `FolderOpenPicker`.

Answer (score 2):

AS [@Tóth Tibor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1406798/t%C3%B3th-tibor) suggested, the multiple file picker UI is not designed for selecting all items. Picking the top level folder should be a solution.

If we need to request a new feature, please submit a feedback in [Windows developer feedback site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform). For the same feature request item, please vote it.